# Network Split Screen

Tags: wireless, networking, display

I've got a PC with the newest Ubuntu installed and 2 Laptops.
Is it possible to split the screen of the PC over Network to the 2 Laptops (and the standard Monitor of the PC which I normally use)?
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this doesn't directly answer your question, you might want to consider a program called Synergy. It allows you to use one mouse/keyboard across all three computers. That way you can still take advantage of the cpu power on the laptops instead of just using them as a remote display. Imagine running a torrent client on a laptop along with a browser to display stuff while coding/writing papers while keeping the cpu of your main machine free to do other things. It is also useful to have one laptop running windows for programs that don't play nice with wine. Sure you could use virtualbox, but a physical windows machine can be nice to have at times.

Comment: My answer was 18 seconds too slow...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, BUT only with a lot of configuration and setting up servers. I tried it myself some time ago but it didn't work out.

I found a good alternative called [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/).

With synergy you could use one mouse and keyboard (including copy-and-paste) on all of your PC's.

Comment: At least I know someone is as 'off' as I am :)